# HTML based troubleshooting decision tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, decision-tree

I am new to creating complex code on HTML and J.script, I have been working with server hardware maintenance and resolving OS issues for 4 years. I wanted to create a web based troubleshooting decision tree which I could host online that would help anyone in need on performing logical troubleshooting on servers. I was able to get an example code from twoseven.co.nz, (courtesy Dan) which matched my requirement but I think I am doing something wrong.

I am able to get output correctly till question_1_2_2,

Though It doesn't go ahead and doesn't show output for step3 option21

I have added the code, it would be great if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Decision Tree - Server Logical Troubleshooting</title>
      
      
      <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>
      
      <style type='text/css'>
        fieldset {margin:10px 0;}
    .hide {display:none;}
    
      </style>
<!--
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
<!-- commented out external stylesheets due to relative URLs.
-->        
    
    
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    
    var base = {
        productFilterSetup: function() {
            $('.productFilter').each(
            function() {
                var tmp = new base.filterGroup(this);
                tmp.setup();
            });
        },
        filterGroup: function(filter_group) {
            var me = this;
            me.target_element = filter_group;
            me.active_element_index = 0;
            me.setup = function() {
                $(filter_group).find('input[type=radio]').bind('click', function() {
                    me.update(this);
                });
            };
            me.update = function(target_radio) {
                var fieldsets = $(me.target_element).find('fieldset'),
                    len = fieldsets.length,
                    i = 0,
                    j = 0,
                    radios, 
                    radios_len, 
                    options = [],
                    options_buffer = '',
                    num_of_steps = 0;
    
                for (i = 1; i <= num_of_steps + 1; i += 1) {
                    if ($('fieldset.step' + i).length > 0) {
                        num_of_steps += 1;
                    }
                }
    
                for (i = 0; i < num_of_steps; i += 1) {
                    if ($(target_radio).parents('fieldset.step' + (i + 1)).length > 0) {
                        for (j = i; j < num_of_steps; j += 1) {
                            $('fieldset.step' + (j + 2) + ' input[type=radio]').attr('checked', false);
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                    radios = $(fieldsets[i]).find('input[type=radio]');
                    radios_len = radios.length;
                    for (j = 0; j < radios_len; j += 1) {
                        if ($(radios[j]).is(':checked')) {
                            options.push(j + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                fieldsets.addClass('hide');
                $('fieldset.option0').removeClass('hide');
                for (i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
                    options_buffer += options[i];
                    $('fieldset.option' + options_buffer).removeClass('hide');
                }
            };
        }
    };
    
    $(
    function() {
        base.productFilterSetup();
    });
    //]]> 
    
    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <h4>No POWER</h4>
      <form action="#" id="unique_id" class="productFilter">
        <fieldset class="step1 option0">
            <legend>Is the Server in a Rack?</legend>
            <p>
                <input id="question_1" name="group_1" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_1">Yes!</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="question_2" name="group_1" type="radio"/>
                <label for="question_2">No.</label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="hide step2 option1">
            <legend>Are other servers in the Rack receiving Power?</legend>
            <p>
                <input id="question_1_1" name="group_2" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_1_1">Yes</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="question_1_2" name="group_2" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_1_2">No</label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="hide step2 option2">
            <legend>Try Different Wall Sockets, Still No Power</legend>
            <p>
                <input id="question_2_1" name="group_3" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_2_1">Yes</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="question_2_2" name="group_3" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_2_2">No</label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="hide step3 option11">
            <legend>The Rack Power is fine, Try different power sockets in Rack, Still No Power?</legend>
            <p>
                <input id="question_1_1_1" name="group_4" type="radio"/>
                <label for="question_1_1_1">Yes</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="question_1_1_2" name="group_4" type="radio"/>
                <label for="question_1_1_2">No</label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="hide step3 option12">
            <legend>Check Rack Power (PDU) and Main Power and UPS</legend>
            <p>
                <input id="question_1_2_1" name="group_5" type="radio"/>
                <label for="question_1_2_1">Yes</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="question_1_2_2" name="group_5" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_1_2_2">No</label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="hide step3 option21">
            <legend>Reseat the power cables on the server PSU ,Still No Power</legend>
            <p>
                <input id="question_2_1_1" name="group_6" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_2_1_1">Yes</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="question_2_1_2" name="group_6" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_2_1_2">No</label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="hide step3 option22">
            <legend>Its an Issue with the wall socket</legend>
            <p>
                <input id="question_2_2_1" name="group_7" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_2_2_1">Resolved</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="question_2_2_2" name="group_7" type="radio" />
                <label for="question_2_2_2">No</label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p>Troubleshooting Flowchart</p>
    <a title="A button." href="#" class="buttonGreen"><span></span></a>
      
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: I made [a fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/whcvon6c/) and it seems to work. I chose No, then Yes, then got the option 3 output ( which is class="step3 option21". And it doesn't look to me like there's supposed to be any output when you choose an option on step 3. So, I'm not exactly clear on what is wrong.

Comment: I added the code snippet to the post, too. In both the code snippet and the jsfiddle, I removed the references to the external style sheets, since they use relative URLs.

Comment: It looks like it works correctly. 'No', 'Yes' gets you to 'step3 option21'. If it isn't working, please elaborate on what the problem appears to be.

Comment: Jakar, Alvin, thanks for getting time out of your schedule and looking in to this. I was at a mind block yesterday as I was doing this alongside my primary job :), I didn't realize the code works till I saw Jakar's js.fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Also this code is a test, I am new to this and I have 7 flowcharts that I made that i'll be converting to a web form, some of the flow charts have about 100-150 questions all with yes and no. If this ain't the idle method, it would be great if you'll could share your experience. Appreciated :)